# Execute scripts for all files in a folder

Tags: bash, scripts

I have following script which i need to execute for all files in a folder.

```
pdftk "file1.pdf" output uncompressed.pdf uncompress
```

```
sed -e "s/text need to remove/ /" uncompressed.pdf > unwatermarked.pdf
```

```
pdftk oldfile.pdf stamp stamp.pdf output final.pdf
```

How to apply all files in a folder may be with a for loop?

Comment: Uhh, can you please apply that instructions to above commands. Thanks.

Comment: I cant give numbers to resulting files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the next:

```
cd /home/user/folderwithpdfs
for f in ./*
  do pdftk $f output unc.pdf uncompress
  sed -e "s/text need to remove/ /" unc.pdf > unw.pdf
  pdftk $f stamp stamp.pdf output $f.pdf
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Salut!

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for my_file in ./*.pdf; do

    filename=`sed "s/.*\///" <<< "$my_file"`;
    #yor comnd using $myfile or $filename
done;
exit;
```